# How to remove the Existing javascript function for the button

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

```
<input name="mybutton" type="button" class="agh" id="id_button" value="Dim" onClick="resetDims();">
```

In the above Input tag i have to remove the entire "Onclick=myfunction();" and its function  for the input tag and write my functionality for this button when we "click"

```
$("#mybutton").onclick(function(){
  //$("#mybutton").removeattr("onClick","");
})
```

Comment: Yes, and what is your question?

Comment: `mybutton` is the element's name attribute, you need to query for `#id_button`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to remove the `onclick` attribute "on-demand" use

```
$('#id_button').removeAttr('onclick').click(function(){
});
```

Have a **second look** at the **selector**. You need to query the `ID`, your snippet
trys to select `mybutton` as ID, which infact is the name of the element.

Comment: Thanks Andy It Worked out for me

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `unbind` to remove an [inline model](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html) onclick handler. `unbind` will only work with jQuery-bound event handlers. It can be done like this:

```
document.getElementById("id_button").onclick = null;

// you can still get the element using the jQuery shorthand though
// the point is to get at the DOM element's onclick property
$("#id_button")[0].onclick = null;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ax52z/

Answer (score 1):

Use `unbind` to remove event listeners.

```
$("#mybutton").click(function(){
  $(this).unbind("click");
})
```

(also, `$().click`, not `onclick`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [jQuery unbind function](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) if you want to remove the click event.

```
$('#mybutton').unbind('click');
```

Comment: Yep, I would go with the approach jAndy explained since unbind does not work in the same case with my app.

Comment: @jAndy - He hadn't added the HTML code to make it clear it was an inline event at the time I answered.